# Requests to docker private registry behind nginx are handled by an HTTPS vhost

Tags: docker, nginx, https

I have a docker private registry container serving behind Nginx in HTTP.

Everythings works fine until I add an HTTPS server configuration. `docker pull` and `docker push` requests are handled by this HTTPS vhost rather than the docker registry vhost (access logs are printed under HTTPS domain, docker registry domain got nothing).

So, obviously, I got 404 errors.

Deleting this HTTPS config makes it work again.

This is my docker registry conf under `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name docker-registry.my-domain.com;
    access_log /data/log/nginx/$server_name.access.log;
    client_max_body_size 0;

    location ~ \.*$ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
}
```

And the HTTPS vhost under `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name foobar.my-domain.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/foobar.my-domain.com/crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/foobar.my-domain.com/key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log /data/log/nginx/$server_name.access.log;

    location ~ \.*$ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foobar.my-domain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

When I use `<my-ip>:5000` as `insecure-registries` rather than the domain name of docker registry, everything works also fine.

When I use curl to send request to
`http://docker-registry.my-domain.com/v2/<my-image>/manifests/latest`, access log of docker registry prints `401 Unauthorized` as expected.

Do I misconfigure Nginx?

Docker version:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.0-ce-beta1
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        78a6bdb
 Built:             Thu Sep  6 22:41:53 2018
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.0-ce-beta1
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       78a6bdb
  Built:            Thu Sep  6 22:49:35 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

Many thanks!

--------------- Updates ---------------------------

I find that it works fine if I remove the protocol `ssl` after listen  in HTTPS config.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found, if `ssl` is also enabled in `docker-registry.my-domain.com`, everything works fine. I don't know why, but it really works.